# find and get + set item value to another Iqueryable list of same type

Tags: c#, list, iqueryable

I have two lists List1 and List2 . I need check wether List1 has value for List2 by comparing itemID field.If It exist in List1 then copy corresponding itemQty value to itemQty  in List2 
The itemQty in List2 is always blank.Here both are a very heavy(large data) Iqueryable lists.

how to do this?
what am doing wrong here?

```
var value = currentOrderlist.SingleOrDefault(x => x.item == curOrder.item).Qty;
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
 {
   gridinfo.Qty = value;
 }
```

alwyas gives error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Comment: Do you want to combine both IList into a new one containing all the keys of both IList (common and orphan) priorizing the value of the second one if the id appears in both?

Comment: @Mark "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Comment: i assume that value is sometimes null, then value.ToString() will throw that exception.

Comment: @Mark How to handle this situation ~ values can be null sometimes.. how to get this working?

Comment: what type is `Qty` by the way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at: [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Add a check if the value is not null before you're trying to do something with value:

```
var value = currentOrderlist.SingleOrDefault(x => x.item == curOrder.item);
if(value != null)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value.Qty.ToString()))
    {
       gridinfo.Qty = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope! gives same error:"Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Inner Exception:null

Comment: see my edit that was because you are trying to access `Qty` on a null return from `SingleOrDefault`

Comment: Yep that worked i was not handling those null values!!